# React Router v4 ConnectedRouter is not rendering on nested routes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux

The first level routes are rendered correctly from **Layout.tsx** but  on **ResourcesUI.tsx** is not rendered when  is clicked (see code below).

ResourceUI component have 2 sections. the left section have links and right section have component that when links from the left is clicked, the right component should be rendered accordingly.

Like I said above, the resource component is routed correctly but the  inside the resource component is not rendering when  is clicked.

**index.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <ConnectedRouter  history={history} >
            <Layout />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Layout.tsx**

```
import routes from "routes"

<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
         <div className="col-sm-3">
              <SidebarContainer />
          </div>
         <div className='col-sm-9'>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
              <Route exact path="/services/:id" component={ServiceDetailsContainer} />
              <Route exact path="/services/:id/resources" component={ResourceContainer} />
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal-root">
        <ModalContainer />
    </div>
</div>
```

**ResourceContainer.tsx**

```
class ResourceContainer extends React.Component<any & RouteComponentProps<{}>>{
    render() {
        const service = this.props.services.find(x => this.props.match.params.id === x.Id.toString());
        return (
            <ResourcesUI service={service} resources={service.Resources} match={this.props.match}/>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: AppState) {
    return {
        services: state.services.serviceRecords
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ResourceContainer);
```

**ResourcesUI.tsx**

```
class ResourcesUI extends React.Component<any & RouteComponentProps<{}>> {

    render() {
        return (
            <section>    
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-3">
                            <div className="panel panel-default">
                                <div className="panel-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        {
                                            this.props.resources.map(x => {
                                              // /services/:id/resources/:resourceId  
                                              const path = `${this.props.match.url}/${x.Id}`; 

                                                return (
                                                    <li key={x.Id}>
                                                        <NavLink to={path}>
                                                            {x.Name}
                                                        </NavLink>
                                                    </li>
                                                );
                                            })
                                        }
                                   </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-sm-9">
                            // THIS ROUTE IS NOT RENDERED WHEN LINK ABOVE IS CLICKED
                           // /services/:id/resources/:resourceId
                            <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/:resourceId`} component={detailfoo} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            );
    }
}

const detailfoo = () => (
    <section>
        <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-body text-center">
                Hey yo!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-body">
                Hey yo!
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);

export default  ResourcesUI;
```

**UPDATE**

I had to add the nested route in the parent layout.tsx as well to make this work. If some one has better solution let me know. :)

```
<Route exact path="/services/:id/resources" component={ResourceContainer} />
<Route exact path="/services/:id/resources/:resourceId" component= ResourceContainer} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your resources comp with withRouter. This will allow non direct descendants of your Router to have navigation props.

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: I added `compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(ResourceContainer)` like the documentation suggested and it didn't work.